# Does one have to say the Shahada, even if one is born a Muslim?

Tags: shahada

If one is born a Muslim, does that person still has to say the Shahada, or he/she won't be considered a Muslim?

Comment: Azaan is given in the ear of muslim baby, the baby is considered a muslim and after he/she is of age, he/she is taught about tauheed and other pilgrims of islam.

Comment: I am not sure how one could be "born" muslim? Being born in a muslim country? or a muslim family? What about families where the husband and wife are of different religions? What about non-practicing muslims?

Comment: As a Muslim you are repeating the shahadah several times a day in your prayer in the adhan, the iqamah and maybe even in your conversation. I wonder if any Muslim wouldn't say it in a daily manner!

Answer (score 1):

One doesn't say Shahada, **one believes in Shahada**.

SO, if one remains a Muslim, it is understood that he still believes in Shahada. But anyways, you say that in each and every prayer of your Salah.

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of obligatory conditions for a human to be Muslim but five most common ones are:

1. Saying [Shahadah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahada)
2. Offering salah five times a day.
3. Doing fast in Ramadan for one month a year.  Saum
4. Visiting Kaaba if in proper conditions by mean of budget at least once in whole life.  Hajj
5. Giving zakat

Like offering Salah, it is also another obligatory course for being Muslim. However, on the other hand, a person may not be in condition to speak or may not know about this but feels that he/she is Muslim. **At that time we should consider that one is a Muslim when he/she accepts what "Shahadah" expression dictates.** But we must also search hadith for this.

Answer (score 0):

No, shahada is obligatory for someone to enter islam, if he/she is born muslim it is not required except if he left islam then to get back the shahada is obligatory.

source:

http://consult.islamweb.net/consult/index.php?page=Details&id=2205665

Answer (score 0):

If the person does not believe Shahadah with full heart, s/he is not considered as a muslim since it is one of the condition of being muslim and being a born-muslim is not one. May Allah guide you. Assalamu alaikum.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the purpose of Shahada explains it's need.

Shahada is literally to bear witness.... when we say that someone who accepts Islam needs to recite the shahada it is to say that this is point in which direction has changed for the individual their actions that demonstrated what they bear witness to with their life have now changed direction and the physical act of announcing their faith is the turning point.

However, is it possible for someone to change their life and live a new set of values without declaring them, and people witnessing that declaration? Absolutely. Once someone is living the values they believe in, they are bearing witness to their faith. We see shahada of a muslim through his hands, his words, his eyes, his feet by all being in compliance with what Allah has asked us to perform.

Therefore, it's not even required that someone recite the shahada outloud to accept Islam, one can live the values of Islam and acknowledge in his heart his role and relationship with the creator to be a Muslim.

We recite the shahada aloud to give us strength, and reaffirm the desires of proximity to God and his true path that is in our hearts.

Hope it helps :-)